# Uso de PIVOT SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente script bastante sencillo:

```
SELECT 
 t.NumeroSolicitud
,t.NombreCliente
,t.CodigoCliente
,t.Mes
,t.FechaPrincipal
,t.SaldoAPagar
,t.FechaPagada
,t.SaldoPagado

FROM Tabla t
```

que me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
NumeroSolicitud  NombreCliente   CodigoCliente  Mes  FechaPrincipal   SaldoAPagar   FechaPagada          SaldoPagado 
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       1     2022-01-12         3087.86       2022-01-12   3087.86
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       2     2022-02-12         3126.46       2022-02-12   3126.46
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       3     2022-03-12         3165.54       2022-03-12   3165.54
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       4     2022-04-12         3205.11       2022-04-13   3205.11
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       5     2022-05-12         3245.18       2022-05-12   3245.18
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       6     2022-06-12         3285.74       2022-06-12   3285.74
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       7     2022-07-12         3326.81       2022-07-12   3326.81
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       8     2022-08-12         3368.40       2022-08-12   3368.40
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       9     2022-09-12         3410.50       2022-09-12   3410.50
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       10    2022-10-12         3453.13       2022-10-12   3453.13
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       11    2022-11-12         3496.30       2022-11-12   3496.30
45855134647      USUARIOPRUEBA    5556789       12    2022-12-12         3540.00       2022-12-12   3540.00
```

hasta ahí todo normal, el tema es que quiero que se vea de esta forma, solo que para todos los meses esta es una muestra de unos 4 meses

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que con usar PIVOT puedo obtenerlo, pero nunca he usado PIVOT, si alguien me ayuda porfavoz

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si hay varias filas para el mes de enero? ¿Hay que poner, que fecha?, ¿Qué valores, se suman? Completa un poco más el ejemplo, para poder darte una respuesta más adecuada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La buena noticia, es que no necesitas aprender a usar PIVOT. En especial porque usando PIVOT con varias columnas puede ser sumamente ineficiente y complicado.

Para obtener una mejor solución, usamos algo que llamo *Agregado Condicional*, que consiste en usar CASE dentro de las funciones de Agregado como SUM y MAX. Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo y espero que puedas completarlo ya que consiste en copiar, pegar y modificar los grupos de columnas.

```
SELECT NumeroSolicitud,
        NombreCliente,
        CodigoCliente,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1 THEN Mes END) AS Enero,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1 THEN FechaPrincipal END) AS FechaPrincipal_Enero,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 1 THEN SaldoAPagar END) AS SaldoAPagar_Enero,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 1 THEN FechaPagada END) AS FechaPagada_Enero,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 1 THEN SaldoPagado END) AS SaldoPagado_Enero,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN Mes END) AS Febrero,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN FechaPrincipal END) AS FechaPrincipal_Febrero,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN SaldoAPagar END) AS SaldoAPagar_Febrero,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN FechaPagada END) AS FechaPagada_Febrero,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN SaldoPagado END) AS SaldoPagado_Febrero
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY NumeroSolicitud,
        NombreCliente,
        CodigoCliente;
```

Comment: Cuando comentas que el uso de PIVOT es sumamente ineficiente y complicado, ¿A que te refieres? Te refieres a que puede llegar a hacer que la consulta pierda rendimiento(velocidad de ejecucion)? Pregunto porque tengo problemas con eso y quiero saber si el uso de PIVOT lo ocaciona o es en parte por ello.

Comment: Así es. No aplica en todos los casos, pero al momento de necesitar varios PIVOT en la misma consulta se puede ir incrementando el tiempo y recursos necesarios. Mientras tanto, con el agregado condicional se mantiene constante porque solo requiere leer los datos una vez.